# Зачем дополнительно передавать аргументы в do_action() Wordpress, если они уже переданы функции

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть код (приведен ниже), который используется, чтобы продемонстрировать работу хуков WP.
Возник вопрос:
зачем в `do_action( 'my_hook' );` дополнительно передавать аргументы `$a` и `$b`, если они уже приняты функцией `do_my_hook()` при ее запуске, обработаны, и мы получим результат их обработки?
А по связке `add_action( 'my_hook', 'do_my_hook');` - `do_action( 'my_hook' );` просто запускается эта функция.

```
<?php 
// Определяем аргументы для хука action
$a = $defined; // $defined какая-нибудь динамическая логическая переменная
$b = 'А это значение второй переменной';

// Включаем хук. Здесь он будет выполняться
do_action( 'my_hook', $a, $b );


function do_my_hook( $a, $b ){
    // если переданная переменная $a равна true,
    // то, например, удалим запись 10
    if( $a===true )
        wp_delete_post(10);
    // а тут просто выведем переменную на экран
    echo '<br />'.$b; // выведет значение второй переменной
} 
// Регистрируем хук через
// add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
add_action( 'my_hook', 'do_my_hook', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы говорите что аргументы уже переданы в функцию, но аргументы в функцию ведь и передаются из `do_action()` (Вы же делаете ее вызов используя `do_action()`) или Вы можете показать какое-то другое место где Вы еще  их можете передать или передаете?

В WordPress `do_action()`, можно сказать, что это некий аналог использования или вызова ф-ции в PHP, а Вы ведь аргументы передаете при вызове ф-ции, верно? В тоже время `add_action()`, это аналог создания ф-ции, а при создании вы ведь туда не передаете никаких аргументов, аргументы Вы передаете уже при ее вызове.

> если они уже приняты функцией do_my_hook() при ее запуске, обработаны,
> и мы получим результат их обработки

Я вижу что Вы немного подредактировали вопрос. Где они приняты и обработаны если Вы, допустим, не передаете их в `do_action()`? Разве у Вас в коде есть какое-то другое место где вызывается функция `do_my_hook()`?

Скорее всего Вы не понимаете сути самого примера. Допустим Ваша ф-ция `function do_my_hook( $a, $b ){}` будет лежать в файле `functions.php`, Вы ее там создали, а делать вызов этой функции при помощи `do_action()` вы будете в файле `header.php` и каким образом Ваша ф-ция получит эти аргументы и откуда, если Вы их не передадите? При написании PHP функции Вы только указываете, что она принимает такие-то аргументы, но Вы их туда не передаете, передаете Вы их при вызове самой функции. Ну и Вы же не думаете что вызов хука при помощи `do_action()` происходит там же где и пишется ф-ция которую Вы туда цепляете.

Comment: Да я просто выделил код - поэтому подредактировал. На самом деле я понимаю то, о чем вы говорите, но есть вопросы, которые мне мешают понять все равно процесс до конца, поэтому пошел копать документацию и сижу думаю ))

Comment: Еще вопрос, который я, видимо, не понимаю: функция do_my_hook, находясь в functions.php не увидит переменную, заданную в другом файле? /* нелегко быть начинающим */ :)

Comment: Я Вас тогда не совсем верно понял и криво сформулировал свой ответ, потом исправил)